# Multiple Column Pivot Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Background:** The application in question allows users to apply tags from a list of available tags. One article can have many tags and each tag may belong to many articles. The relationship between those is fine, but the complication comes in that a user should only see the tags which they have applied to the article. For instance, if Alice applies ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry'] to article #1, Alice should not see Bob's article #1 tags of ['Grape', 'Orange', 'Kiwi'].

**Ideal:** An attach would work where the Auth'd user accesses the tags and applies it to an article by creating records in the intermediate pivot table. Additionally, if a user has applied a tag that does not exist yet, they should be able to insert new tags in the same action.

This action would be similar to how tags are applied to a StackOverflow post, actually.

The code I currently works, but just barely, so I wanted to see how others might organize the relationships between these. I'm also open to using a package if one exists that can handle this logic.

**Relationships:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Article');
    }

    public function articles_tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Article_Tag', 'article_tag_user', 'article_tag_id','user_id');
    }
}


class Article extends Model
{

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Tag', 'article_tag');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function article_tag_user()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Tag', '\App\Article_Tag_User', 'article_id', 'id', 'article_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}



class Tag extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'article_tag_user', 'id', 'article_tag_id');
    }

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Article', 'article_tag');
    }
}



class Article_Tag extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'article_tag';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'article_tag_user', 'user_id', 'article_tag_id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Tag');
    }
}


class Article_Tag_User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'article_tag_user';

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Tag', '\App\Article_Tag');
    }

}
```

**Table Schema**

---

**Tag Table**

|id|name|

**Article_Tag Table**

|id|article_id|tag_id|

**Article_Tag_User**

|id|user_id|article_tag_id|

Comment: How did you organize the relationships?

Comment: I added the models to my post so you could see the relationships I've tried. They work, but just barely and I feel that there's a much more logical way to maintain such a relationship.

Comment: What do you mean by "They work, but just barely"?

Comment: I mean that the code looks rather sloppy and I feel as though there is a better way to write my relationships so I can be flexible in how I'm accessing the underlying data. Currently, two attach operations have to occur for one relationship between a tag and a user to be made since it goes through an article as an intermediary.

Comment: Can you add the mentioned tables and their relevant columns? What's the difference between `Article_Tag` and `Tag`?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post with the table schema. The articles and users tables are fine, so I didn't post those. It's just those in-between tables which are causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one pivot table (it also doesn't need an `id`):

```
article_tag_user: article_id | tag_id | user_id
```

Then you have `BelongsToMany` relationships between all combinations of `Article`, `Tag`, `User`.

Comment: Ah, okay so just define each relationship using the Article_Tag_User as the pivot, then? Like on User I'd do Article and Tag, so on and so forth.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Ah, okay. So it was me overcomplicating things, then. Makes sense.